# Ubuntu ffmpeg can't use libx264

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, h.264, libx264

Command

```
ffprobe rtsp://localhost/myvideo -codec:v libx264 -show_frames -of csv
```

Output

```
Failed to set value 'libx264' for option 'codec:v': Option not found
```

But `libx264` seems to be installed -
`sudo apt install libx264-dev`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx264-dev is already the newest version (2:0.152.2854+gite9a5903-2).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libx264` is an encoder. `ffprobe` only probes and prints information about existing media inputs - there's no scope for an encoder to be specified. Remove `-codec:v libx264`.

Comment: Thanks. Question: is there a way, using a decoder, to ask the encoder to use a certain "amount" of B or P frames? Or is it completely up to the encoder? I am streaming an rtsp video.

Comment: No. You have to tweak whichever software or device is running the encoder.

Comment: Oh, I though rtsp would allow to ask the encoder (on the other side of the network) to encode with different number of B-frames and P-frames